# If android apps can't access other app code, how can one app check another for viruses?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an android application to scan other applications for viruses, or malicious code etc. But to begin with, I'm trying to figure out how existing anti-virus scanning systems operate.

Comment: No rooting required. Have a look at this thread, might give you an idea: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/how-do-anti-virus-apps-for-android-work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its rooting, because there are a lot of anti viruses that don't need rooting. If I have to guess, I would say it scans the files for signature. And they access the files similar to how file explorers work. Someone more knowledgeable can correct me.